# iOS: How to keep showing a subView after pushing to a viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have `viewController` No.1, which has a `subView` showing. And after I push to another `viewController`, No.2, this `subView` does not shown on the screen anymore, which makes sense, since I have pushed to another VC.

However, I hope to keep this `subView` on the screen even though I am in a pushed `viewController` now. So I wonder how I can achieve this?

Comment: either add as a childVC or add the subview to the `UIWindow`

Comment: or you can set background color with alpha 0.0 of ViewController No2.

Comment: Inherit VC2 from VC1? Or make base class with that subview and let both VC's inherit from that class.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
//Create a view in the center of the screen
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2)-50, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2)-50, 100, 100)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

//Create a window class
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
//Pick a level
window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
//Add the view
[window addSubview:view];
```